# Dojo modules in bundle

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dojo, require

Is there a way to add Dojo modules in ASP.NET MVC bundle?
I know that for using Dojo modules, should use `define()` or `require()` and browser loads each module as different .js file. But in pages, where I need to use more modules and browser should load 50 (for example) .js files, this make entire page's load slower.

Thank you!

Comment: I think MVC does not provide it by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no direct way to make a dojo build in an ASP.NET MVC bundle.

But in order to maximize page's load you need to build your dojo application using [dojo/util](https://github.com/dojo/util) and link the resulted files in your HTML head.

A dojo build allows you to:

- Concatenate your modules, so you could send to the client all your code in few js files.
- Minify the source code, which make the code lighter to download (dojo build use Closure Compiper or Shrinksafe).

More information on [The Dojo Build System](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/).

Very useful [dojo boilerplate](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate) to start with.